# javascript sdk - check if user has liked my facebook page (in iframe tab)

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible with javascript SDK check if user has liked my facebook page (I need to check it on my iframe tab (without autorization)). 
It's very simple in PHP , but I need to so it with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Haha! I asked this question last week and got a neg review, which apparently infers that I posted the question without doing the proper research...haha! This is what I've found out since.

1. Facepile, facepile will give you a list of users images who have liked your page...pretty useless as far as I can tell.
2. Running the old rest api from javascript. While this is being depreciated, not all the functionality has been ported over and as far as I can tell //developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isFan/ has not been ported over yet. You'll just have to keep your eyes open for when these do change so you can update when they do port it.
3. Querying with FQL: This looks like the go to for a lot of my stuff. Check out the //developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Data.query/ on how to call fql in the javascript sdk. Tables and columns are detailed here: //developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/#tables

Good luck! Let me know if these make sense.